# buttons with 2 lines of text are larger than buttons with 1 line of text, but i need them all to be the same size as the 1 line

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css

the buttons on my site are sizing up based on how much text there is. when there is 2 lines the buttons are larger than the buttons with 1 line. how can i fix this?

this was fixed at one point but broke again. and this is certainly not all the code for it,

```
.wp-block-column {
  margin-bottom: 0;

  @include desktop {
    height: 138px;
    height: 252px;
    flex-basis: auto;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 36px;
    width: 357px;
    height: 238px;
  }
}

.wp-block-button {
  height: 100%;
}

.wp-block-button__link {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wp-block-columns {
  justify-content: center;
}

.all-button {
  border-radius: 1rem;

  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato-Bold';
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  @include desktop {
    width: 355px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.67rem;
    margin: $base__space-unit;

    border-radius: 8px;

    a {
      font-size: 30px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      #text {
        margin: auto;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i expect all the buttons to be the same size

Comment: Can we see your html code?

Comment: Add `width` and `height` attributes to the CSS class if you want them to be a specific size, otherwise they will be as large as they necessary to contain their content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them exact height Ex.

```
.all-button {
  height: 42px; //Put here size you want
}
```

or Give `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: your whitespace nowrap worked well enough. I need to keep all the same sizes for the buttons, so i think i can get away with whitespace no wrap

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.all-button {
    width: 150px; 
    //or whatever fits your theme
    height: 50px;
    //or whatever fits your theme
}
```

By adding the above code you give exact height and width to your button.